# What is the gist of this quote?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Not to honor men of worth will keep the people from contention; not to
>   value goods that are hard to come by will keep them from theft; not to
>   display what is desirable will keep them from being unsettled of mind.

The first two sentences, do they mean the following:

**People will stop contending if they stop honoring worthy men.**

**Valuable goods will not be stolen if they are not appreciated.**

In the last sentence, "them" is referred to what? And what does "unsettled of mind" mean? And what is the gist of the whole sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The two sentences you suggest are correct interpretations. But the 2nd sentence could be more clearly stated in the same way as the 1st :

**People will not steal scarce goods if they do not appreciate the value of those goods.**

In the last sentence - as well as in the 2nd - "them" refers to "the people". "Unsettled of mind" means having troublesome thoughts, such as thinking about stealing something - while also thinking that it is wrong to steal things.

The gist of the whole is a warning that materialism causes social strife.